# why collection repect not show alternate color in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework .I make a simple demo of table using **ng-repeat** In this I make alternate color of each row which is running perfectly
here is perfect code in which I used ng-repeat

I used I ng-repeat

```
<ion-scroll scrollbar-y="true" delegate-handle="i" ng-style="viewHeight">
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="column in inv | limitTo: counter  track by $index" ng-class-odd="'odd-row'">
    <div class="col brd collapse-sm" ng-repeat="field in column.columns" ng-show="d_column_name[$index].checked && d_column_name[$index].d===field.d">{{field.value}}</div>
    <div class="col col-10 text-center brd collapse-sm"></div>
  </div>
</ion-scroll>
<ion-infinite-scroll immediate-check="false" on-infinite="loa(query)" distance="10%"></ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Now I change   **collection-repeat**  instead of **ng-repeat** I face few issues

here is my code which I use **collection-repeat**

I face few issues

- There is no alternate colors in row when application run
- when I scroll down bottom after few seconds it show alternate color.but when user scroll up then automatically it show alternate row color why ?
- how to remove gap between the rows ?

I used this isead of **ng repeat**

```
 <ion-content class="padding">

        <ion-scroll scrollbar-y="true" delegate-handle="i" ng-style="viewHeight">
          <div class="row" collection-repeat="column in i   track by $index" ng-class-odd="'odd-row'">
            <div class="col brd collapse-sm" ng-repeat="field in column.columns" ng-show="i_column_name[$index].checked && i_column_name[$index].d===field.d">{{field.value}}</div>
            <div class="col col-10 text-center brd collapse-sm"></div>
          </div>
        </ion-scroll>
      </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 solutions :

with ng-class-odd and ng-class-even

```
<div collection-repeat="item in items" ng-class-odd="odd-row" ng-class-even="even-row"></div>
```

or with ng-class

```
<div collection-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'even-row':$even,'odd-row':$odd}"></div>
```

or with plain css

```
ion-scroll div.row:nth-child(even) {background: red}
ion-scroll div.row:nth-child(odd)  {background: blue}
```

finally to avoid using odd and even helpers

```
 <div collection-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{white:$index%2 == 0,blue:$index%2 == 1}"></div>
```

**EDIT :** update class name to match yours

don't forget to declare these classes to see the difference :

```
ion-scroll .even-row{background: red}
ion-scroll .odd-row {background: blue}
```

Comment: pls give plunker ..so that i wll check

Comment: it's working. define the `.white{background:red;}` and `.blue{background:blue;}` class in the css.

Comment: working for me : http://plnkr.co/edit/bZ6PNj6hTxUxo6Xnt1cZ?p=preview just add `.white div, .blue div {background : transparent}` to your css

Comment: how to remove space ?

Comment: please check your solution when scrolling ? it breaking when alternate color

Comment: ok I see now. It's an issue with collection-repeat. Because it's deleting rows that are not in the viewport, so the odd and even class aren't fixed. sometimes the row is odd sometimes it's even. I'm trying something else

Comment: it's working a bit better with : `ng-class="{white:$index%2 == 0,blue:$index%2 == 1}"` but it's not very clean. you should avoid to put divs in other divs. when I empty the lines the style applies correctly.